# Mysql error on Toad "failed parsing insert command"

Tags: mysql, toad

I am very new on Mysql. I am using Toad for Mysql. I created a database (mydb), I created a table(user) and I inserted a record to my table by using gui of Toad. When I click enter I got this error on Toad:

```
Internal Error. Failed parsing insert command. Please send to Yahoo group for fixing
```

and just below this code:

```
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user` (`id`, `name`, `role`) VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3)
```

My records are commited successfully but I keep getting this error.
There is no clue on Google as far as I searched.

What is the problem exactly and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never seen that problem before. There are far better tools than toad for mysql though.

if you are on a budget and need something free, checkout navicat lite and sqlyog community edition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've copied and pasted that INSERT statement from somewhere and its used an incorrect character for the quotes. you seem to have ` rather than '. A subtle but important difference. Although this could have happened when you pasted it here rather than into TOAD.